# Macbook touchpad multitouch stopped working

Tags: macbook-pro

Actually, two fingers for scrolling still works, but all other gestures don't. None with 3 or 4 fingers, and even side scrolling notification panel with 2 won't.

Out of the blue, it just stopped!

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found on [apple boards](https://discussions.apple.com/message/10525076#10525076):

> <sup>by [Majicman](https://discussions.apple.com/people/Majicman) in Nov 13, 2009 1:13 AM</sup>
>
> I'm an Apple technician who works for a self-servicing provider. This happened to me today as well. Reboot didn't fix it, neither did a new user account.
>
> Here's what I did that did indeed fix it:
>
> - Boot into [single user mode](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201573). (hold down <kbd>command + S</kbd> on reboot)
> - Wait for the `#` prompt
> - Type exactly this: `fsck_hfs -f /dev/disk0s2`
>
> When it's done, type `shutdown -r now`
>
> Your Mac will reboot. Hopefully that fixed it for you, too!

For whatever reason I couldn't get into single user mode, so I just hold <kbd>option</kbd> and opened the Terminal there. Worked for me! :)

*( I just [wished I knew what the bleep disk0s2](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fsck_hfs%20-f%20%2Fdev%2Fdisk0s2%22%20touchpad%20why%20disk0s2) has to do with anything here! )*

Also, [someone else mentioned there](https://discussions.apple.com/message/10525076#10525076) the `fsck_hfs` didn't work for them but this did:

```
/sbin/fsck -fy
```

Comment: Try running `diskutil info /dev/disk0s2` — it should be your boot disk.

Comment: That helps a bit. `diskutil list` also says it's type `Apple_CoreStorage` with no name. My boot disk is probably `disk2`, though, which I left the default name `Mac OS X` and it's type `Apple_HFS`. `disk0s3` is `Apple_Boot` named `Recovery HD`.